# Prevent user from seeing pages that require a session

Tags: php

I've got a login page then I made a link to a page called logout and it contains this code:

logout.php

```
<?php

session_unset();
session_destroy();
header("Location:");

?>
```

Yet when I log out then hit the back button it takes me back. How do I change it so that it ask you to login again before showing you your previous page?

Comment: Make sure the browser does not cache the page.

Comment: I have no idea how to do that, could you possibly show me by posting?

Comment: This is how browsers work, the page isn't reloaded when you hit the back button. Example, I will post this comment, click on a link to another question, and press back. I won't see my comment.

Comment: Specify `Expires:`, `Cache-Control:` and `Pragma:`  using `header()`. [Example](http://www.hardcode.nl/subcategory_4/article_279-no-cache-headers.htm).

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Prevent going back page after log out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6648093/php-prevent-going-back-page-after-log-out)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not set any location to redirect to.

Should be:

```
 header("Location:http://example.com/login.php");
```

This way when you logout, it will redirect the browser to login.php.

**EDIT:**

Also, it would help to add a session validation condition to your main page.

Somenthing like:

```
 if(!isset($_SESSION))
 {
     header("Location:http://example.com/login.php");
 }
```

Comment: Ok. Have in mind @Script47,that when you hit back in your browser you are accessing to a cached version of your page.

Comment: It might not work if the browser open a cached version. But you can avoid that, if you also add to your code some [no cache headers](http://www.hardcode.nl/subcategory_4/article_279-no-cache-headers.htm)

Comment: Full URLs should be used in header redirects, not relative paths.

Answer (score 3):

On the page you're going back to (or any page for that matter) you need to do checks to see if the user is logged in or not (i.e. has a valid session) and if not, redirect them to the login page.

Additionally, it might help for you to add some no-caching headers to this particular piece of code.

Answer (score 1):

Before loading every page (or atleast, every PRIVATE/RESERVED page) you should check the $_SESSION variable to determine if the user is legally logged in or not.

If you don't perform this check, everybody would be able to visit every page of your website if they have the direct link to it. They may see a broken version of the page, but the access is granted nevertheless to not logged users.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    session_start();
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
    session_write_close();
    setcookie(session_name(),'',0,'/');
    session_regenerate_id(true);
?>
```

source: [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-unset.php)

Answer (score 1):

try this  to check on each page if the user is logged in

```
if (!$_SESSION['logged_in']) { //you would have to make $_SESSION['logged_in'] when they login
header('location: login.php');
}
```

all this does is say if $_SESSION['logged_in'] is NOT set redirect them to the login page.

You would also need to other checks to make it secure.